# Is there a way to know whether a window is in windowed or fullscreen mode?

Tags: lwjgl, glfw

I can't find anything about this. I know GLFW has a way to get attributes:

[GLFW: window related attributes](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_attribs)

But nothing to check if a window is in windowed mode.

The reason I want to know this, is that when the current monitor gets disconnected the window
is set to windowed mode. But I don't know if it gets "restored" to full-screen" when the monitor reconnects.

I currently store a boolean in the window class for whether the window is in windowed mode.
And use this when i change resolutions etc. I can set "windowedMode = true" when the
monitor disconnects. But atm. I can't know if I should set it to false if it reconnects.

I only have one monitor (laptop) and can't test this out for myself. Either way, it could be useful
to know if you can query that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GLFWmonitor* monitor = glfwGetWindowMonitor(window);
```

"For windowed mode windows, this function returns NULL. This is how to tell full screen windows from windowed mode windows."

[GLFW: Window monitor](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_monitor)

If the return value is NULL it could also be an Error, so you would have to check for that:

[GLFW: Error handling](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#error_handling)